# Why 奇蹟 (and not 奇迹) In Simplified Texts

Tags: writing, traditional-vs-simplified

I often run across the word 奇蹟 in simplified texts written just like that: `奇蹟`.

For example:

1. [Yes](http://twent.chinayes.com/Content/20140422/kiuvg0712tp0w.shtml) has an article entitled:

`【上帝之子】全美票房创18亿台币奇蹟`.

Here's an excerpt also with said writing (emphasis is mine):

> 全台湾预售票票房告捷 各地要求映演声不断
>   此生必看圣经电影【上帝之子】（Son of God）不但在美国上映至今已创下十八亿台币票房**奇蹟**，在台湾，藉着教会的支持，电影还未上映亦已有近两百万的包场及预售票票房成绩，更因观众的要求，陆续增加各地映演戏院，目前全台上映戏院包括台北信义威秀影城、欣欣秀泰影城、今日秀泰影城、板桥秀泰影城、新竹巨城威秀影城、台中Tiger City威秀影城、台南大远百威秀影城、高雄大远百威秀影城、花莲秀泰影城以及台东秀泰影城等十家。

2. [China Times](http://www.chinatimes.com/cn/realtimenews/20150104000011-260408) also has an article entitled: `飞机失事 女孩奇蹟逃脱残骸敲门求救`

and excerpt:

> 根据英国每日邮报报导，一架私家小飞机周五坠落在美国肯塔基州地区，机上5人中有4人丧生，但1名7岁女孩**奇蹟**生还，自行走出坠机现场，跑到陌生人家敲门求救。机上罹难者除了小女孩的父母，还有她的9岁姊姊与一名14岁表哥。

蹟 has been simplified to 迹.

The writing of 奇迹 is, still, far more common.

The question is then, why do some still insist on writing 奇蹟 in simplified texts?

Comment: As far as I know, in a formal text in simplified Chinese (currently used in the mainland), 奇蹟 must be simplified to 奇迹.But in HK or Taiwan where people use traditional Chinese,  all the characters in a text will be in traditional form, and no simplified Chinese is expected to appear.

Comment: The answer may be simple. 1) TW and HK use 蹟 and 跡. Sometimes   the usages of these two characters are distinguished, but dating back to *Shuowen*, they were treated just as variant characters. 2) Then, when there's only a mapping for 跡 but none for 蹟, the machine translation from traditional Chinese to simplified Chinese will be wrong -- Yes, 奇迹 is the only correct simplified form.

Comment: There are quite a lot of flawed texts on the internet, even on official news sites.

Comment: In simplified Chinese, it should always be 奇迹. If not, that's a typo.

Comment: 蹟, 跡 and 迹 are different variant of the same character. But 迹 is rarely used in HK & TW, in simplified Chinese (mainland China) 迹 is the unique character for them. see this: https://tw.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080806000051KK02820

Comment: Other similar pairs: 線 and 綫, 娘 and 孃.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

迹 is not a simplification of 蹟. 迹 is a simplification of 跡, though.

蹟 is a **variant** character of both. It can be used in either script, as one pleases.